# Changing routes doesn't refresh data, gives ng:areq error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-routing

In my AngularJS app, I have a route that looks like:

```
.when('/:project/:page', {
    templateUrl: '/ui-editor/editor',
    controller: 'EditorCtrl'
})
```

In a view, I have a link that looks like:

```
<a href="/{{currentProjectId}}/{{currentPageId + 1}}">Next page</a>
```

When I click that link in my app, the URL in the browser changes correctly (e.g. `/myproject/1` to `/myproject/2`), but I get an error [`Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'scope' is required`](http://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng%3aareq?p0=scope&p1=required). The line that the error refers to is the `console.log` statement in:

```
socket.on('ws:init-data', function(data) {
    console.log('on ws:init-data', data);
    // Handle incoming data from server
    //...
});
```

If I refresh my browser, the correct data loads as it should for `/myproject/2`.

Answer (score 0):

use `ng-href` is better. It can avoid link be clicked before angular parse.

```
<a ng-href="/{{currentProjectId}}/{{currentPageId + 1}}">Next page</a>
```

I don't know the exact cause about this error, but I have a suggestion:

## use $location to change your url.

you can see on the dev_guide:

### When should I use $location?

*Any time your application needs to react to a change in the current URL or if you want to change the current URL in the browser.*

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location

Comment: Thanks. But how would I use `$location` to change the URL? You mean not use the `ng-href` tag anymore?